# meaning of "Application does not run in background"

Tags: iphone, ios

In the Plist, one of the setting is

> Application does not run in background -------> YES

Does **YES** means **application does run in background**. 
And what happens to the application after that...

Comment: Opting out of background execution is "strongly discouraged" by Apple.(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the value for this option to `YES` means that your application will exit when suspended by the OS.  See [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) for a more detailed explanation of this option.

Answer (score 6):

YES means that the application will be killed when the user will press the main button.
Consequently, the app re-start totally when the user try to re-launch the app. (it's the same behavior as the iPhone 3G)